# Sony Alpha 77M2 Remote control over USB

Tags: usb, sony-camera-api

I have three Sony Alpha 77M2 cameras, and I'm trying to take photos with all three simultaneously, and retrieve these photos. I can do the simultaneous shutter release using commercial remote triggers synced off a single transmitter, and I can control a single camera over USB using the Sony Remote Camera Control software - however this can't control more than one camera, and it won't let me run more than one instance on a single machine.

My question, therefore, is whether there is an API available for the USB remote control interface for these cameras? They don't support the WiFi API, so I can't use that (and WiFi isn't much use for the environment this system will be used in, due to the likelyhood of interference)

Comment: A77m2 supports limited WiFi your post is misleading.

Comment: It supports limited WiFi - but it doesn't support the full Sony WiFi API. Which is what I said in my post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that the camera supports enough of the PTP protocol for libgphoto to recognise it and retrieve the images in tethered mode - but not to control the shutter.

Comment: Read the bug I sent you! You need to change the USB connection mode of the camera to PC Remote Control

Comment: The link you sent was for the A7, not the A77 - different camera, with different things supported. As it is, the A77 is now supported by gphoto