# Remote Camera Control API/SDK over USB for Sony Camera

Tags: c#, camera, usb, sony

I can see that Sony made an application named Remote Camera Control that controls a Sony camera over USB. Is there somewhere where I can find maybe the API or SDK to communicate with this camera like the Remote Camera Control does?

Comment: Could you find anything relevant for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of ressources on [Developer Sony website](https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/)

Unfortunately, Remote control over USB is not possible using public API. This might be modified in a soon futur by Sony but for the moment you have to give a look to unofficial library like this [Github projet](https://github.com/alech/alphamote) which try to provide such control (but is 6 years old and has not been updated since).

This [post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586156/sony-alpha-77m2-remote-control-over-usb) refer to "the PTP protocol for libgphoto" which seems an option ... I don't know much about that.

What about [Sony Remote camera control](http://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/imsoft/Win/rcc/us.html) which might provide some API ... worst case you can have some code to simulate a click (like a robot) but thats a terrible option :D

Comment: That is the remote API to control the camera over wifi, not over USB. I need USB because I need to do Continuous Shoot and I cannot do continuous shoot with that API with the A6000 which is the camera that I am using.

Comment: Found an unofficial library to do so, I updated my answer in consequence.

Comment: Few years later, and Sony already released SDK which allows remote USB/Ethernet/WiFI control (CrSDK) ;)